# a modal popup extender form to be used and called in all pages as needed

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, master-pages, modalpopupextender

I have a modal pop up extender which contains a gridview that loads all location, the user can open this pop up form to select a location and used for searching purposes. 4 pages in my website project will be needing the same form for searching, instead of creating the same individual form per page, can i use the created modal pop up extender form by just calling it from different pages? are there ways to do that?

I am thinking of putting it in a master page, but do not have an exact method or ways on how to do it.

Any help will very much appreciated! thanks in advance

Comment: why are you not creating user control ???

Comment: thank you very much for replying, I am actually new in asp.net programming and I searched about user control, so this can be done to achieve what I want in the system?

Comment: Yes. But you have to try it first. Good Luck

Comment: I've done it already, thanks user control can be used to achieve what i want with the system to have a reusable controls.